# I am trying to import mysqldb for django. 'my_config.h ' no such file or directory is the error that i am getting

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, python-3.x

Initially i got that error called vcvarsall.bat not found.To resolve that i installed Microsoft visual studio 14 .After that the error i got is

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop\mysqlclient-1.3.7>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing top-level names to mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
. ..
...
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No    such file or directory
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio  14.0\\VC\\BIN\\
cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have no clue how to proceed. I am using Windows 8 and Python 3.5 .

Comment: I've no solution for this problem, but you could install the [Mysqlclient wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) instead.

Comment: The Mysqlclient appears to give the exact same error. I tried to install it when the mysql-python package gave me the error. The file its complaining about is where it says it isnt.

Answer (score 0):

mysqlclient uses a library from MySQL.

For Windows, install a libmysqlclient here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Then try reopening your cmd.